# Плагин галереи в окне

Tags: jquery, gallery

Подскажите плагин-галерею в отдельном окне со следующими критериями:

1. Изображение в отдельном окне
2. Открытие нескольких окон
3. Возможность независимо перемещать окна (по примеру http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Лишних наворотов, типа показ превью изображений, не обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну таких плагинов просто нет. Ибо смысла в такой логике нет. В 98% это не требуется.

Есть два варианта, но их просто напросто придётся допиливать самому.

**Первый.**

Банально при клике на картинку открывать новое окно, через **[window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)** и там триггерить событие плагина всплытия модального окна. Новое окно как раз можно будет перемещать, как вы хотите, вызывать еще и т.д.

Как пример, взять **[fancybox2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license)**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 if (typeof imageUrlOpen !== 'undefined') {
  $.fancybox.open( [imageUrlOpen] );
  $(document).on('click', '.fancybox-close', function () {
   window.close();
  });
 }

 $(document).on('click', '.fancybox', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var el = $(this);

  PopupCenter(location.href, getRandomInt(1, 999), 800, 600, function (winHandle) {
   winHandle.imageUrlOpen = $(el).attr('href');
  });
 });
});

    // для генерации индивидуального идентификатора для окна
 function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
 }

    // окно по середине экрана
 function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h, callback) {
  // Fixes dual-screen position                         Most browsers      Firefox
  var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
  var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

  var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
  var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

  var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
  var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
  var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

  // Puts focus on the newWindow
  if (window.focus) {
   newWindow.focus();
  }

  callback(newWindow);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<p>
  <a class="fancybox" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8140/30366640446_eb359921c5_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8140/30366640446_eb359921c5_m.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
  <a class="fancybox" href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/756/22625719192_fdc3369588_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Etiam quis mi eu elit temp">
    <img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/756/22625719192_fdc3369588_m.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
  <a class="fancybox" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8542/29466009773_a809b99d19_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Cras neque mi, semper leon">
    <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8542/29466009773_a809b99d19_m.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
  <a class="fancybox" href="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1514/23919332220_60b7867d60_b.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Sed vel sapien vel sem uno">
    <img src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1514/23919332220_60b7867d60_m.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
</p>
```

В сниппете работать не будет..... ну потому что новые окна и сниппет. Поэтому стоит как демо у себя попробовать.

Тут как раз генерируется новое окно. А также проверяется, есть ли переменная в окне `imageUrlOpen`. Если определена, значит надо производить триггер. Если нет — оставлять все в покое.

В общем случае это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Второй** - он как следствие первого. Если не нравится такой стандартный вид окна, то тогда делайте, например через **[iframe](http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe)**, который можно будет стилизовать через `css`, а также назначить события закрытия (удаления) фрейма, когда он будет не нужен.

Но только придется присобачить что-то из *draggable* плагинов, чтоб заставить фрейм двигаться.

А логика появления модального окна будет примерно такой же, то есть, по сути, вызов будет примерно таким:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fancybox', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this);

    $('body').append('<div id="iframe-wrap"><iframe src="' + location.href + '" width="800" height="600">Ваш браузер не поддерживает плавающие фреймы!</iframe><div id="iframe-close"></div></div>');
});
```

css типа

```
#iframe-wrap, iframe {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

и так далее.